# Cast varchar to byte[]

Tags: .net, t-sql, casting, binary, varchar

Get bytes from a varchar
[word] is varchar(600)
The problem with the follow code is it always retrieves 30 bytes.
If [word] is longer than 30 the bytes is truncated.
If [word] is shorted than 30 then it is packed with 0s.
How can I retrieve the actual number of bytes.
Yes I really need the bytes of the [word].

Limit of 5 tags:  SQL 2008 R2,  C#

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBytes charSB;
byte[] charB;
Int32 id;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "select [ID], cast(Rtrim([word]) as binary), [word] " + 
                     "from [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) order by [word];";
SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
    charSB = rdr.GetSqlBytes(1);
    charB = charSB.Value;
    stringByte1252s.Add(new StringByte1252(id,charB));
}
rdr.Close();
```

This works

```
  select top 10000 [ID], cast(Rtrim([word]) as binary(4)), len([word])
  from [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) order by [word]
```

But I cannot pass a len([word]) as the size of the binary
Varbinary throws the same error
The following throw an error
msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '('.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 2

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a
>   common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking
>   context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a
>   semicolon.

```
  select top 10000 [ID], cast(Rtrim([word]) as binary( len([word]) )), len([word])
  from [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) order by [word]
```

Comment: Try casting as varbinary(max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the MS pages: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188362(v=sql.105).aspx

*"When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1. When n is not specified with the CAST function, the default length is 30."*

You need to specify the length in the cast to avoid the default of 30 - if the length is not known in advance or could vary, use a varbinary with a large value for the size or even a varbinary(max) - this will also prevent unnecessary padding of the value since binary is a fixed width field.

Comment: You would need to know the length in advance, I would cast it as a large varbinary or even varbinary(max) - then you can handle any size you wish up to the maximum, whilst not padding the result (which a binary would do)

Comment: Do you mind adding that to the answer and I will accept?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the variable in .net, I would recommend not casting it to binary in SQL.  Instead, read it as a string, since that is what the original column is.  Once you have it as a string, you can get the bytes using the [System.Text.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) class for whatever code page you need.  The available code pages are listed at the bottom of the doc page I linked.

Code might look like this:

```
SqlCommand sqlCmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
byte[] charB;
Int32 id;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "select [ID], Rtrim([word]), [word] " + 
                     "from [FTSwordDef] with (nolock) order by [word];";
SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
    charB = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(rdr.GetString(1));
    stringByte1252s.Add(new StringByte1252(id,charB));
}
rdr.Close();
```

Comment: This is a case of as actually want to get the bytes. Long story.

Comment: OK. I'll leave the answer up in case it helps someone else.

Comment: I agree leave it up. +1  I may have to use this TSQ seems to want a hard value for binary size.